# RadScheduler update interval

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, setinterval, radscheduler

I'm using RadScheduler for my project. In the scheduler, I need a periodical update, so in my javascript, I set interval for a method that call rebind() on the RadScheduler for every 60 seconds. The problem is that, when my user open the advanced form, the rebind() method makes the form disappear. How can I detect AdvancedForm opening and closing event so that I can stop /restart the timer ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While there is an event for when the RadScheduler opens its Edit form, called [OnClientFormCreated](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-onclientformcreated.html), there is not one for when the edit form closes. There are ways to do this though, but you have do add some additional code.

When you think about it there are several different items that can lead to the form closing - the user can click on the close icon at the top right (or left, depending on your orientation) of the window, they can click cancel, or they can hit save.

Keeping that in mind, we can take a look at [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/advancedformtemplate/defaultcs.aspx), which shows the Advanced Edit Form in action, and also has some JavaScript pre-written for us.

Within the `schedulerFormCreated()` function we can do the following:

```
        function schedulerFormCreated(scheduler, eventArgs) {
            // Create a client-side object only for the advanced templates
            var mode = eventArgs.get_mode();
            if (mode == Telerik.Web.UI.SchedulerFormMode.AdvancedInsert ||
                mode == Telerik.Web.UI.SchedulerFormMode.AdvancedEdit) {
                // Initialize the client-side object for the advanced form
                var formElement = eventArgs.get_formElement();

                var cancelButton = $("[id$='_CancelButton']");
                cancelButton.on("click", formClosed);

                var templateKey = scheduler.get_id() + "_" + mode;
                 ....
```

And then we have the formClosed event:

```
function formClosed(eventArgs) {
}
```

in formClosed you can just create your logic for resuming the timer, while in schedulerFormCreated you can directly call the function that stops the timer right after that if-statement.

In case you're wondering what we're doing here we're simply grabbing an instance of the jQuery object representing the element with an id that ends with _CancelButton (we're not interested in the beginning part) and then just binding to the click event using the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jQuery function.

To get an instance of the save button you just have to use **_UpdateButton**, and for the close icon it is **_AdvancedEditCloseButton**. Keep in mind that *any* element that ends with these substrings will be selected, so if you want to be more specific I recommend inspecting the elements of your advanced form using FireBug or the Chrome Dev tools to get their ID and plug that into the selector above.

This should allow you to get the functionality you're looking for.